# Why this code is compiling?

Tags: c#, params-keyword

Assume I define a method like this:

```
public static void ListInts(int[] inVals)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inVals.Length; i++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", inVals[i]);
    } 
}
```

If I try call it like this, obviously i'm getting an error and code will not compile:

```
ListInts();
```

***Method 'ListInts' has one parameter(s) but is invoked with 0 arguments***

But when i change method definition like this:

```
public static void ListInts(params int[] inVals)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inVals.Length; i++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", inVals[i]);
    } 
}
```

There is no error.I'm curious why this is happening ? And why second code is compiling without any errors? What happens behind the scenes when we use `params` keyword ?

Comment: First Google hit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What effect did you expect the `params` keyword would have?

Comment: Are you sure you know what `params` do exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have easily search for the reason in the documentation.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

> By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments.
>   You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration or an array of arguments of the specified type. **You also can send no arguments**. If you send no arguments, the length of the params list is zero.
>   No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

Answer (score 3):

The params keyword makes a function into a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). Variadic functions can take anywhere from 0 to (in theory) infinite arguments. So that is why your code compiles. The string.Format function is a classical example of a variadic function.

If you want to create a variadic function that has to accept at least one parameter, you can do the following (in C#):

```
   int methodname(int arg1, param int[] restOfArgs) {}
```

At which point you will be forced to give at least one argument to the function

Answer (score 2):

MSDN link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

> By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that
>   takes a variable number of arguments.You can send a comma-separated
>   list of arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration
>   or an array of arguments of the specified type. You also can send no
>   arguments. If you send no arguments, the length of the params list is
>   zero.No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword
>   in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a
>   method declaration.

Comment: Is these your words or you copied it from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/w5zay9db.aspx) page? `:)`

Comment: @SonerGönül Wrapped the text into block quotes (@sonu, FYI), please reconsider if you downvoted the answer.